# How do I change the mapId of a Google vector map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

With Google's raster maps, I could create a map with an initial style like this (example taken from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)):

```
var mapStyles = [{ elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{ color: '#242f3e' }]}];
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945 },
    zoom: 12,
    styles: mapStyles 
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions );
```

Then, I could change the style like this:

```
var newStyles = [{ elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{ color: '#ffffff' }]}];
map.setOptions({ styles: newStyles });
```

With the vector based maps, instead of specifying the style in code, I need to specify a map ID. That map ID will have a style that someone configured in the cloud. I created two of these map IDs (a normal theme and a dark them) following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-based-map-styling#change-map-style), and then instantiated my map like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945 },
    zoom: 12,
    mapId: 'abcd1234mymapid'
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions );
```

I tested both map IDs to be sure the theme was working. The problem is that I can't figure out how to change the map ID after creating the map. I want to allow the user to switch between map IDs. I tried:

```
// Does not work
map.setOptions({mapId: 'efgh5678myothermap'})

// Also does not work
map.mapId = 'efgh5678myothermap'
```

Is this functionality gone with Google's vector maps or am I doing it wrong?

I did make sure to include both map IDs when loading Google's script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&v=weekly&callback=yourInitMapMethod&map_ids=abcd1234mymapid,efgh5678myothermap"></script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, the only workaround to switch from one style to another (changing mapIds) is to create a new map instance. **Note** that each map instance is billed. As per [Dynamic Maps Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps). You can do something like this:

```
//Event that triggers change of map style
document.getElementById("map_id_1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  mapID = "YOUR_MAP_ID"
  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      ...sharedOptions,
      mapId: mapID,
      useStaticMap: false
    });
});
```

Here's a complete [JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/1qhgmeo9/4/) you can try.

Dynamically changing the mapId through the `setOptions()` function currently is not possible as it appears that mapId is not yet added as a property of the [MapOptions interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions) as per the documentation.

I already filed a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/161501609) in Google Maps Public issue tracker to support for this.

Comment: Looks like mapId has been added to the MapOptions.

Comment: Looks like even though it's in the options docs, you still cannot change it dynamically. I get this error in the console: `Google Maps JavaScript API: A Map's mapId property cannot be changed after Map construction. Please set the Map's mapId in the constructor MapOptions.`