# Google Maps Javascript API Cloud based styling

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

Anybody understand how to use the "Cloud Based Map Styling" for the Google Maps Javascript API?

I've been following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-based-map-styling) but it doesn't actually explain how to to use the Map ID once it's been associated with the styling.

The only advice I could find was this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62947623/2565840), but I'm trying the script below and although a map appears, there is no style applied to it.

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    mapId: "t43vt7y4ct837ytv", //not my real Map ID
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: { lat: 51.4765924, lng:  -0.003 },
    zoom: 15.5
  });
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure the mapid is also in your script loading tag and that you are using the weekly version.

Comment: Looks like they've removed this key information from the documentation for some reason!

Comment: @velsietis please don't share your API keys on public websites

Comment: @jabamataro thanks for spotting that! ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ecg8 (and from a more careful read of the question [How do I change the mapId of a Google vector map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62780394/2565840)) I also needed to supply the Map ID as with the `map_ids` query parameter in url of the script loading.

As an example see url in the script tag below.

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&v=weekly&callback=yourInitMapMethod&map_ids=abcd1234mymapid,efgh5678myothermap"></script>
```

I'm assuming this will be added back into the official documentation for the API, but at the moment I can't seem to find it, so answering my own question here.

Comment: I was using "map_id" in the query and that dose NOT trigger the custom style. Using "map_ids" (mind the s!) even with one single Map_id does trigger the correct style. That is not mentioned in the documentation.